# sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Object category_tb('23','cat1','cat1desc','0') is not legal as a SQL literal value

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

Beginner At Flask. I was trying to change a number in an instance on every updates but it doesnt seem to work,

here's my code

```py
if form.validate_on_submit():
    getcat = category_tb.query.filter_by(cat_name=form.cat_name.data).first()
    
    getcat.currentnum = getcat.currentnum + 1

    mynum = getcat.currentnum
    mycode = getcat.cat_id
    itemcode = mycode+'-'+mynum

    added = master_item_tb(item_name=form.cat_name.data, item_id=itemcode, cat_id=mycode)
    db.session.commit()
      
    flash('New Item has been Added To The System!', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('items.html'))
```

for every items added the code should automatically increases like code item should have different number everytime new item added

For the form I can't seem to find any faults here:

```
class newitemForm(FlaskForm):

    def getcat():
        return category_tb.query

    item_name   = StringField('Item Name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=20)])
    cat_name      = QuerySelectField('Category', validators=[DataRequired()], default='1', query_factory=getcat, get_label='cat_name')
    hd_unit     = StringField('Head Unit', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=8)])
    sub_unit    = StringField('Sub-Unit', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=8)])
    hd_qty      = IntegerField('Head Qty', validators=[DataRequired()])
    sub_qty     = IntegerField('Sub Qty', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit      = SubmitField('Submit') 

    def validate_item_name(self, item_name):
        
        pid = master_item_tb.query.filter_by(item_name=item_name.data).first()
        if pid:
            raise ValidationError('Item Already Existed, Please Select Another Name')
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is on the route but I cant seem to find any problem.  I keep getting
this error

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Object category_tb('23','cat1','cat1desc','0') is not legal as a SQL literal value

Comment: i forgot to add one more thing which is  db.session.add() but that is not the main problem

Answer (score 0):

in

```
    added = master_item_tb(item_name=form.cat_name.data, item_id=itemcode, cat_id=mycode)
    db.session.commit()
```

you forget to add the object to be commit, There for nothing changes in the table

Modify that part to:

```
    added = master_item_tb(item_name=form.cat_name.data, item_id=itemcode, cat_id=mycode)
    db.session(added)
    db.session.commit()
```